# How to select a secondary menu item as the focus of "Accessibility Inspector" in Mac OS?

Tags: macos

Specifically, I'm trying to select iTunes' menu item "File > Library > Export Library" but it interprets clicking on "File" as locking AI's focus, rather than activating file. The NEXT click activates the File menu, but then I can't switch the focus to the menu item I'm really interested in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press <kbd>option</kbd><kbd>space</kbd> after the first click on "File", then move the cursor through the menu, then <kbd>option</kbd><kbd>space</kbd> again to lock on the element you want.